# Excel vba for loop changing loop variable inside a loop

Tags: vba, excel

Lets say I have a For loop similar to this:

```
Sub forLoop()
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim aRow As Integer
firstRow=5
lastRow=200
For aRow = firstRow to lastRow
   If (something) Then  //lets say it happened when aRow = 18
       aRow=aRow+1  //=> aRow=19 
       ...
   End If
Next aRow  //which one ? will next aRow be 19 or 20?
```

And I increment a aRow variable inside the loop. Would it result in that variable being incremented twice as much?

Answer (score 2):

If you'll debug your code you can see the value yourself. Below code results in

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim firstRow As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim aRow As Integer
    firstRow = 5
    lastRow = 200
    For aRow = firstRow To lastRow
        If aRow = 7 Then
            aRow = aRow + 1
        End If
        Debug.Print aRow
    Next aRow
End Sub
```

output as

[image]

Here, `aRow = aRow + 1` increments the value of `aRow` by `1` and is subsequently reflected in loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

Run the this simple script:

```
Sub forLoop()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 100
    If i Mod 5 = 0 Then
        i = i + 1
    End If

Debug.Print i
Next i
End Sub
```

As you can see with the output, when i is 5 it is forced to 6 and then the next loop is 7.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will get a one-time bump:

```
Sub forLoop()
    Dim firstRow As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim aRow As Integer
    Dim i As Long

    firstRow = 5
    lastRow = 200
    i = 1

    For aRow = firstRow To lastRow
       If (aRow = 18) Then
           aRow = aRow + 1
       End If
       Cells(i, "A") = aRow
       i = i + 1
    Next aRow
End Sub
```

[image]