Dynamically Inserting a row and iterating over it in VBA?
During reverse iteration of a range of cells (down to up going right to left), a row is inserted above the current one and and shifts down.
Sub ReverseIterateAndInsertRowRestart()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim columnToCheck As Long
    Dim startRow As Long, startColumn As Long

    ' Set the worksheet and define the initial range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:E10") ' Adjust as needed

    ' Initialize starting row and column
    startRow = rng.Rows.Count
    startColumn = rng.Columns.Count

    ' Iterate through each row from bottom to top
    For r = startRow To 1 Step -1
        ' Iterate through each column from right to left
        For c = startColumn To 1 Step -1
            ' Check if the cell is blank
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(r, c)) Then
                ' Insert a copy of the current row above
                rng.Rows(r).Copy
                rng.Rows(r).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                rng.Cells(r, c).ClearContents ' Clear the specific cell in the copied row

                ' Update the range to include the new row
                Set rng = ws.Range(rng.Cells(1, 1), rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count))

                ' Adjust the row counter to account for the new row
                r = r + 1
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub

How would one ensure the iteration continues to the newly created row (as though it were already there)? Tried adding r=r+1 with no luck. Can't seem to update the loop.

What are you trying to do? What is your input and expected outcome?

You can't change the loop counter inside the loop. It belongs to the for block. You need to use a while loop instead and manage the counter yourself. while r > 0, and you can increment or decrement r yourself as needed.

@KenWhite "You can't change" or it can't be changed?

@rotabor - it can be changed, just not a good idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035603/excel-vba-for-loop-changing-loop-variable-inside-a-loop

@Michal It can be useful sometimes.

@Michal, Hello. Am trying to get the inserted row evaluated next in the loop.

No, it's never a good idea to alter the loop counter in a for loop. Most real languages will not allow it, and trying to do so in your code will result in a syntax error that prevents compilation.  VBA may allow you to change it, but doing so is absolutely wrong. If you have a need to alter the variable, you need to use a different type of loop, such as the while loop I suggested previously.

@KenWhite Don't be so categorical.

@JohnMiller Why do you not want to use my code? It works. May be, I didn't make what you need exactly, but you can change it as you need.

I'm stating facts. If you want to write code, learn to do it the right way, so that you can get things done. Don't be so set on doing something wrong when someone who knows better tries to educate you. Don't be so stubborn about being right that you shoot yourself in the face rather than listening when someone tells you not to look down the barrel of a loaded gun. Altering the loop variable inside a for loop is WRONG. If you have a feeling that you need to do that,  stop and find the proper loop structure instead. Maybe you'll learn something in the process and accomplish something.

@KenWhite You should not propagating your opinion as a rule. And you should not think you are able to teach somebody else. You can share your opinion, of cause. Everybody who find something useful in it will use it.

@KenWhite And you overuse bold.

@rotabor: Bold is used to add emphasis, and I used it properly and sparingly. I used it exactly three times in my last two comments. And if you think modifying a for loop variable is acceptable, you're the one who should not be teaching anyone. You should find something to do other than trying to fumble your way around programming until you accidentally stumble across something that works, no matter how wrong it is, and then claim you're an expert.

@KenWhite I do not teach anybody to modify a for loop variable anywhere above. Probably, you consider yourself as an expert?

@rotabor: I don't claim to be anything. I have 40+ years of programming experience in various languages. I've been around long enough to know that you use a for loop to run a section of code a specific number of times, and if you have a need to alter the loop control variable, you're no longer trying to run a specific number of times, but instead are trying to run until a condition is met, which means that a for loop is the wrong type of loop. This is plain common sense for anyone who knows anything at all about writing code. It doesn't take an expert or a rocket scientist to understand.

@rotabor Just tried your solution. Also modified it to use Do while. It works in both loops except that the range is not updated. After inserting, row 1 still points to the old row (not the inserted) because it gets the same row in the next loop. How do we update the range with the new row so it gets it in the following iteration?

@JohnMiller To get clarity, it would be appreciated if you could provide us with the source range and the desired result (depict).

@KenWhite Your approach is understandable and reasonable. But, having ~40 yrs. and bla bla bla, I don't assume the prescribed 'for' construct as something absolute. For me it's just the shorten for initialize, change, and test of the cycle variable. And it's my approach. Other PLs (you should know) have more advanced 'for' construc which allows to control the cycle variable better.

@rotabor: No, a for loop is absolutely designed to run a block of code a specific number of times. That's an undebatable fact in every language. It's also a fact that if you're altering the loop variable, then you've altered the intent of your code to no longer do what a for loop is designed to do, and it's a fact that there are other loop constructs that are more suitable. If you feel you have to abuse the for loop in a way that it is not intended to be used, you need a different loop type, and if you insist on misusing a for loop instead, you're a poor programmer.

@JohnMiller You don't need to replace for by do in my code. To Ken's satisfaction, there is no change to the loop variable.

@JohnMiller Is this comment "Clear the specific cell in the copied row" correct? Do you need to clear the content in the copied row or in the row has been copied?

@rotabor: No, it's not to my satisfaction. You're still misusing a for loop. Let's use a simple example. If you have 15 rows, your loop is designed to iterate downward from 15 to 1. If a row is inserted and needs to have something done to it, you no longer have 15 rows, and therefore a for loop is the wrong construct. Your solution of introducing another variable is a hack (that doesn't work), not a fix. The fix is to use a while loop, as I mentioned 3 hours ago. A for loop is simply one type of control structure. There are others.

(continued) There's an old adage about there being more tools in the toolbox than a hammer. A hammer works well when doing what it's designed to do (drive nails), but not so well when fixing a broken window pane. Learn to use the proper tool for the job. In this case, the proper tool is not the for, but a while.

@KenWhite My solution works as far as I understood OP's need. My approach to use for in this task is to provide the required countdown variable for iterate over existing rows (which is required following OP's code) rather than over the growing range.

@KenWhite You can provide your solution instead of this discussion.

@KenWhite I can help you get rid of your misconceptions. You wrote: "I've been around long enough to know that you use a for loop to run a section of code a specific number of times", but in VBA and other languages (may be, not in all) the 'for' statement doesn't specify the number of times to repeat. It specifies the loop variable initial value, the loop variable limit to don't trespass, and the loop variable changing step. Ruby is the only language which I know where 'times' method does exactly what your say.

@KenWhite You wrote: "Most real languages will not allow it, and trying to do so in your code will result in a syntax error that prevents compilation." Can you enlist some of such languages? In your activity records I found 'c#' and 'c++' tags. In these PLs you can modify the cycle variable. Moreover, I can state what the very concept of "loop variable" does not exist as such.

@KenWhite So, I can summarize: 1) you propagate your opinion as a rule; 2) you present false arguments in support of your opinion; 3) you appeal to the incompetence and unprofessionalism of your opponent.

@KenWhite For my sad, Microsoft tells: "For...Next statement ... Repeats a group of statements a specified number of times".. Of cause, there is no clause in the statement declaration to specify the number of times. Moreover, Microsoft doesn't explain anywhere in that article how to calculate the number of times. In such command e. g. For i = 1 To 123456 Step 123, are you able to say fast the number of times? Are you able to say if it loops for 123456 or not?

@KenWhite Evidently, this conception "it's never a good idea to alter the loop counter in a for loop" is based on the statement "For...Next statement ... Repeats a group of statements a specified number of times". The wrong basis causes the wrong conception.

@KenWhite I provided Microsoft the appropriate feedback about the explanation for "For...Next statement". The correct explanation is indirectly provided in the "Remarks" section.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@rotabor: No, thanks. I'm done beating a dead horse. If you haven't been able to understand by now, no amount of repeating myself is going to change things. And the wrong basis isn't mine, which is confirmed by exactly what you quoted in that comment - Repeats a group of statements a specified number of times, which was what I've explained here several times already. Altering the loop control variable in the loop violates the specified number of times that the loop started with, which means it's the wrong kind of loop. But, as I said, if you haven't understood by now....

@KenWhite Ok, one thing has remained: pls. show me where 'for' specifies a number of times.

@rotabor: WTF do you think the for x = 1 **to** 10 does? In that example, 10 is the upper limit of the loop, which means it's supposed to iterate exactly 10 times. If you haven't understood that out yet, you should go back and find a very, very, very basic tutorial. I'm done here. This is getting to be just ludicrously stupid.

@KenWhite So, do you restrict 'for' to use only with the integer-type variable as a loop counter and 1 as the start value? Once again, For i = 4253 To 123456 Step 123?

@KenWhite Truly, for x = 1 **to** 10 repeats the statement block 10 times, but it's not that stated here, it's the result of execution of this statement. But the statement tells: 1) assign 1 to x; 2) execute the statement block; 3) increment x by 1; 4) if x<=10 then go to step #2 otherwise end. The value of x in the step #3 is not restricted anyway.

@KenWhite "it's never a good idea to alter the loop counter in a for loop" - it's a conception, approach, or a programming pattern. And it's invented not by you. It has a right to exist. But it doesn't mean that is the best or it should be used every time everywhere.

@KenWhite You can have a look at the updated description in "For...Next statement ... Repeats a group of statements while the loop counter approaches its final value".

A big thank you to @Ken White. Indeed to backdown rows, one has to monkey with the loop. Please see the following paragraph. Also a big thank you to @rotabor for his variants. His theorems pass the test but fail in practice. They don't take into account variadic rows (having different number of columns) and mixed. However, I would kindly ask that he doesn't delete them, because they are valuable learning materials. They have been immensely helpful. I will also state the same for the comments (all of them).
Because we are iterating backwards and inserting rows above the current row, we also have to push the limit (0) backwards to account for the added rows.
So here is a real-world use-case solution (simplified).
Option Explicit ' Force explicit variable declaration. 

Sub ReverseIterateAndInsertRowRestart()
    ' Firstly, sort the fields if rows have mixed data to avoid duplicates.
    ' Use a procedure that looks good to you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79082783.
      Call SortBlanksOnTop
      
    ' Set up your variables and turn off screen updating.
      Dim t As String
      Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, d As Long, e As Long
      Dim r As Range ' Working range
      Dim Cell As Range, Left As Range, LeftTop As Range
      Dim insert As Boolean
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Set title for the range selection user dialog box.
      t = "Selection Range"
    
    ' Request and store range from user.
      Set r = Application.InputBox("Range", t, Application.Selection.Address, Type:=8)
      
    ' Initialize.
      a = 0
      b = r.Rows.Count
      
    ' Iterate through each row from bottom to top.
      Do While b > a
        ' Assume no row has been added
          insert = False
        
        ' Iterate through each column from right to left within that row
          For c = r.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
              Set Cell = r.Cells(b, c)

            ' Calculate the relative column number within the range
              d = Cell.Column - r.Columns(1).Column + 1
            
            ' This condition is based on the example data and layout provided below. Please adjust to your needs.
            ' Skip formular cells and only proceed if there are 2 additional columns to the left of the selected range.
              If Not IsEmpty(Cell) And Not Cell.HasFormula And d > 2 Then
                  Set Left = Cell.Offset(0, -2)
                  
                ' If row above exists, compare values
                  If Cell.Row > 1 Then
                      Set LeftTop = Left.Offset(-1, 0)
                      If Left.Value <> LeftTop.Value Then
                    ' Indicate that a row has been added
                        insert = True
                      End If
                  Else
                    ' Indicate that a row has been added
                      insert = True
                  End If
                  
                  If insert Then
                    ' Copy the current row
                      r.Rows(b).EntireRow.Copy
                      
                    ' Insert the copied row above the current row
                      r.Rows(b).EntireRow.insert Shift:=xlDown
                    
                    ' Clear the contents of the current column in the newly inserted row
                      Cell.Offset(-1, 0).ClearContents

                    ' Calculate the relative row number within the range
                      e = Cell.Row - r.Rows(1).Row + 1
                      
                    ' Adjust the row counter
                      If e > 1 Then b = b + 1
    
                    ' Restart loop for next row
                      Exit For
                  Else
                    ' Exit current row
                      Exit For
                  End If
              End If
          Next c
        ' Count down
          b = b - 1
          
        ' If a row was added, adjust the row limit to account for the new row
          If insert And b <= 0 Then a = b - 1
      Loop
      
    ' Turn screen updating back on.
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

You may add your conditions as necessary to the IF clause.
Example data
(Uses a formula for the numbers)

Result


Use Option Explicit at the top of each module and declare all variables (a, b, c,...), the latter being kind of an SO standard i.e. most answers respect this. If you don't want to share SortBlanksOnTop, at least out-comment it.

@VBasic2008 Thank you for the reminder. Just corrected and added all code.

@VBasic2008 Please check my answer again, just finished updating it.

It's nothing for me, but you write this "but fail in practice. They don't take into account" incorrectly. I modified your code to let it work. "variadic rows (having different number of columns) and mixed" are out of the scope of the answer.

Revise your code. You mix w and r which can be different worksheets.

@rotabor I upvoted your answer. What I meant was whether someone might use your code from anywhere in the worksheet with any number of row and columns arranged in any order. This is the litmus test for this kinds of procedures. For example, if your data starts at line 45 of your worksheet, and you have lots of columns, say 20, you'll need to step back your limit approximately 20 times. This is what I meant, not that your code doesn't work. It works. And Thank you again. Are you able to complete your answer? I can wait and upvote yours. Also, let me know where I mixed the two variables?

w is the active sheet while r is the user entered range which can refer another worksheet. Having c in the middle, you countdown d from r.Columns.Count and manipulate on w inside the loop. I don't know your idea, may be this code good, but potentially it can be an issue. I'm not going to modify my answer since it's complete to show you how to run the loop you need. Good luck!

Here is the solution:
    ' Iterate through each row from bottom to top
    For r = startRow To 1 Step -1
        ' Iterate through each column from right to left
        Dim i As Long ' <<<<<<<
        i = r ' <<<<<<<
        For c = startColumn To 1 Step -1
            ' Check if the cell is blank
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(i, c)) Then ' <<<<<<<
                ' Insert a copy of the current row above
                rng.Rows(r).Copy
                rng.Rows(r).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                rng.Cells(r, c).ClearContents ' Clear the specific cell in the copied row

                ' Update the range to include the new row
                'Set rng = ws.Range(rng.Cells(1, 1), rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)) ' <<<<<<<

                ' Adjust the row counter to account for the new row
                i = i + 1 ' <<<<<<<
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

You need i to track the source row. You don't need to refresh rng.
How it works is shown below.
The source range:

The result:

The code iterates over rows from bottom to top and inserts new rows upon condition.
Or this variant:
    For r = startRow To 1 Step -1
        Dim i As Long
        i = r
        For c = startColumn To 1 Step -1
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(i, c)) Then
                rng.Rows(i).Copy ' <<<<<<<< difference
                rng.Rows(r).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                rng.Cells(r, c).ClearContents
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

The result:

